# Excel 2010 VBA Text to Column for multiple sheets within one workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple sheets within my Workbook.
Two of the sheets (Sheet "A" and Sheet "B") have the following code assigned to them:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

Range("A:A").Select


    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A:A"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub
```

If a text file is copied and pasted into sheet "A", then another text file is copied and pasted into Sheet "B", everything works fine.

If a text file is copied and pasted into sheet "B" first, then another text file is copied and pasted into Sheet "A", I end up with errors:
After the first paste into sheet "B", Dialogue box "Do you want to replace contents of destination cells?" appears. (I answer OK)
Then after I paste into sheet "B" I get the same dialogue box - if I enter "No", the data from column B disappears. If I answer OK, I get a Run time error `'1004': Text To Column method of Range class failed.`
How can I get this code to work independently within each sheet, without errors?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A:A"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**

I had to re-enable **Events**

I then modified the macro as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("A:A").Select
        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A:A"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If there is data in column **B** , I also get the warning...............If I answer **OK** , the override occurs...............If I answer **Cancel** , no error occurs.

Comment: Tried it - no change. I still get the disappearing data if I answer No and the runtime error if I answer OK.

Comment: Thank you - at least the run-time error is no longer an issue.